# Flutter: Adding advertise every nth row in ListView.builder

Tags: android, flutter

In Android Studio, I was using RecyclerView.Adapter and RecyclerView.ViewHolder with getItemViewType() to determine the position of a row in RecyclerView and put advertisement every 10th row. but in the flutter, I don't know how to achieve that and I was looking around the web for the last two days I could not find anything or maybe I don't know what it's called in the flutter. I may not need a code example, I need some guidance on how it's possible or what it's called to look around the web.
Tip: I'm using ListView.builder to receive data from API and show it in ListView.builder.

EDIT: I'm adding my code to make it more clear:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Map data;
  List recentNews;
  var _textController = TextEditingController();

  Future getRecent() async {
    String url = 'https://example.com/api';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: ApiKey});
    data = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      recentNews = data["data"];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getRecent();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: DefaultTabController(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text("TEST", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),
      body:
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: recentNews == null ? 0 : recentNews.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              String serverTime = "${recentNews[index]["createdAt"]["date"]}";
              DateTime time = DateTime.parse(serverTime);
              String agoTime = timeago.format(time);
              return Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        new WebView(slug: recentNews[index]["slug"], title: recentNews[index]["title"]),
                      );
                      Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                            child: new Image.network(recentNews[index]["image_url"])
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Text("${recentNews[index]["title"]}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            ),),
                        ),
                        new Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("${recentNews[index]["source"]["name"]}"),
                            Text(" - "),
                            Text(agoTime),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
    ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `itemBuilder` takes `int index` - simply use it for returning your adverts when `index % 10 == 9` and your "normal" items otherwise

Comment: @pskink I'm sorry I tried my best but it seems I'm not sure where to implement it in my code. Can you show me how to do it please. Thanks in advance

Comment: you have: `itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {` - simply use that `index` in that way that for index 0-8 you return your data, for index 9 you return first advert, for index 10-18 you return your another data, for index 19 you return your second advert etc

Comment: @pskink My issue is after your first comment i did some search and I found this https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list and now I'm confused where to add this index % 10 == 9 and how to make the if statement. because it's kinda different and I don't want to write all of my code again. a real code would be very helpful.

Comment: ok, you have `itemBuilder` - this builder is used for creating your list view items - so it returns  `Widget`s that will be presented on the list view - in your case you will return from it two kinds of `Widgets`: your normal data `Widget`s and the advertisement `Widget`s every 10th position, so you have to make some kind of `if(index % 10 != 9) return DataWidget(); else return AdvertWidget();`

Comment: Ok now I know where to add the if statement, but when I add index % 10 == 9 in my setstate() it gives error. that's where I added it: `Future getRecent() async {
    String url = 'https://example.com/api';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: ApiKey});
    data = json.decode(response.body);
        (i) => i % 6 == 0
        ? HeadingItem("Heading $i")
        : MessageItem("Sender $i", "Message body $i")
    setState(() {
      recentNews = data["data"];
    });
  }`

Comment: see `ListView.builder(
 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
 if (index % 10 != 9) {
 var dataIndex = index - index ~/ 10;
 return Text('data #$dataIndex');
 }
 var advertIndex = index ~/ 10;
 return Container(
 color: Colors.red,
 child: Text('advert #$advertIndex'),
);
 },
 itemCount: 100,
 )` - all you have to do is to use your data here

Comment: @pskink Thanks mate you are amazing I don't know how to thank you.

Comment: your welcome, and of course you have to change `itemCount` too...

Comment: Dear @pskink I know It's bee along time, but I had one issue from the first day fo this solution and it seems I can't pass it. this solution is overwriting the original data so if the list is ten items + on advertisement it only shows ten items and the item which it's in the place of the advertisement will be lost. so I was asking if there's any solution? thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

**Try ListView.separated()**

*In the separated() constructor, you generate a list and you can specify the separator between each item.*

```
    ListView.separated( 
        itemBuilder: (context, position) { 
        return ListItem(); 
    }, 
    separatorBuilder: (context, position) { 
        return Container(child: (index != 0 && index % 5 == 0) ? 
        AdmobBanner(adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(), adSize: 
        AdmobBannerSize.BANNER, listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map args) 
        { //handleEvent(event, args, 'Banner'); },
 ) : Divider( height: 2.0, )); 
        }, itemCount: itemCount, //nth item as ads. 
)
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverflow community. Kindly go through the [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) link tophrase your responses better in order to help the community

Answer (score 3):

Try `ListView.separated()`

In the separated() constructor, you generate a list and you can specify the separator between each item.

```dart
ListView.separated(
      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
        return ListItem();
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, position) {
        return SeparatorItem();
      },
      itemCount: itemCount,  //nth item as ads. 
),
```

This type of list lets you dynamically define separators, have different types of separators for different types of items, add or remove separators when needed, etc.

This implementation can also be used for inserting other types of elements (advertisements for example) easily and without any modification to the main list in the middle of the list items.