# Flutter: How to Properly Load Multiple Native Ads on Listview?

Tags: flutter

How to properly load multiple Admob Native ads on Listview? I am using the google_mobile_ads package.

For some reason the official documentation and examples only work with 1 Native Ad in the ListView. And even shows error if you try to use the same Banner again.

My goal is to show a Native ad every 8 ListTiles. Is there a way to properly do this without using extra packages?

Answer (score 3):

I also went round and round for a solution to this.  Here is how I ended up doing it.  Problem is getting the async ad load process managed when putting  the widget in the listview. My approach was to do the state management in a separate stateful widget that is added to the listview in the separated builder.

```
//the listview or ScrollablePositionedList in my case       
return ScrollablePositionedList.separated(
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if ((index + 1) % 4 == 0) {
                      return  AddAd();
                    } else {
                      return Container(height: 1,);
                    }
                  },
                  itemScrollController: scrollController,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListContent(data[index])
                                            );
                  });
//the reusable statefulwidget for ads
import 'package:antelope/helpers/ad_helper.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class AddAd extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AddAdState createState() => AddAdState();
}

class AddAdState extends State<AddAd> {
  //ad setup
  BannerAd _bannerAd;
  bool _isBannerAdReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {

    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: AdHelper().bannerAdUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (_) {
          //if this is the first banner load set adsready true
          if (!_isBannerAdReady) {
            setState(() {
              _isBannerAdReady = true;
            });
          }
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          print('Failed to load a banner ad: ${err.message}');
          _isBannerAdReady = false;
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );

    _bannerAd.load();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
   _bannerAd.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  //the card takes will either take editable form or view form
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
          _isBannerAdReady ?   Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
                                  height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
                                  child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd),
                                ),
                              ),
                            
                          ): Container(height: 1,);
        
  }
}
```